# Visual Studio Installer with Build Tools and Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Why I am seeing such numbers (2) and (3) for Visual Studio Build Tools and Community 2022 as per the snapshot below?

And how I can resolve the install warnings? I already reported is as per the provided link in the prompt (see screenshots for details)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually means you already have it installed, in another location.

Comment: "How I can resolve the install warnings?" - Use InstallCleanup.exe which is located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#remove-all-with-installcleanupexe) and then simply reinstall Visual Studio.